# Certificate authentication with Cronet (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, cronet

I would like to perform API calls using Cronet (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/cronet#0) with certificate authentication (aka mutual TLS).

I cannot find any documentation or sample. Is there any way to do it?